# Universal kriging with non-zero mean vector

Tags: gaussian-process, kriging

Its is known that in ordinary Kriging (Gaussian Process) the mean and variance at any new point is given as 
$$\\\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{y}\\y^{*} 
\end{pmatrix} \sim N(\mathbf{0},\begin{bmatrix}
 K & K_{*}^{T} \\  
K_{*} & K_{**}
\end{bmatrix})\\y^{*}|\mathbf{y} \sim N(K_{*}K^{-1}\mathbf{y},K_{**}-K_{*}K^{-1}K_{*}^{T})
$$
What is the mean and variance in universal kriging, for example when a linear mean trend is assumed ?